# testing with automated testing

Tags: tdd

I am reading Test driven development by TDD by example KentBenk.

--->Stress--------$----->RunTests
     |
     |<------------$--------|

Above diagram says that if an arrow wiht $ means that an increase in the first node implies a decrease in the second node.

Above is positive feedback loop. The more stress you feel the less testing you do and more errors and more stress.

How do we get out of such a loop? Here authore mentioned that either introduce a new element, replace one of the elements, or change arrows. In this case we'll replace testing with automated testing.

Below is text notes after diagram:

> Did I just break something else with that change? With automated
>   tests, when I start to feel stress, I run the tests. Running the tests
>   immediately gives me a good feeling and reduces the number of errors I
>   make, which further reduces the stress I feel.
>
> "We don't have time to run the tests. Just release it!" The second
>   picture isn't guarantted. If the stress level raises high enough, it
>   breaks down. However, with automated tests you have to a chance to
>   choose your level of fear.

My questions are

1. Can any one represent new feed back with new element automated testing? Here how when I feel stress we run less automated tests with above diagram so how we reduce stress?
2. What does author mean by "The second picture isn't guarantted. If the stress level raises high enough, it breaks down. However, with automated tests you have to a chance to choose your level of fear."?

Comment: Which book are you reading ? Also your question sould be probably asked at programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the book at hand.. but from your quoted passage.

Having quick automated tests makes it possible to

- get fast feedback (within secs of making a change) - did you just break something that used to work?
- run it frequently.. ideally after every tiny change. The faster your test suite the greater the probability that your tests will be run frequently.

The difference with manual testing is that the feedback cycle is too long causing you to bunch a lot of changes before you spend a day/week testing everything (you don't want to lose a day/week after every tiny change). This leads to issues with isolating the change when a defect is found - more stress.